# calculating time between many dated in the same column with group by using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, datediff

i have a  data set which has the number id of customers and the dates of thier orders what i need to do is to calculate the number of days bewtween every order for each customer for example :
[image]

so i need to know the number of days between every order made for every customer . thanks for the help :)

Comment: sql is language..please share your DBMS like `mysql`, `sqlserver` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how you will do this, you can use `dense_rank()`

**MySQL 8.0**

```
select t1.id, t1.order_date
            , ifnull(
                datediff(cast(t1.order_date as datetime), cast(t2.order_date as datetime))
                ,0) as intrval
    from (
            select dense_rank() over (partition by id order by cast(order_date as datetime) asc) as rnk
                , order_date, id 
            from table1) as t1
    left join 
     (
            select dense_rank() over (partition by id order by cast(order_date as datetime) asc) as rnk
                , order_date, id 
            from table1) as t2
    on t1.id = t2.id and t2.rnk+1 = t1.rnk
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: it returns syntax error :
       SELECT t1.account_num, DATEDIFF(day, CAST(t2.checks_log_date AS DATETIME),CAST(t1.checks_log_date AS DATETIME)) 
FROM (
        SELECT DENCE_RANK()  OVER  ( PARTITION BY  account_num  ORDER BY CAST(checks_log_date  AS DATETIME  ) ASC) AS  rnk, order_date, id 
        FROM check ) AS t1
LEFT JOIN  
 ( 
   SELECT DENCE_RANK()  OVER ( PARTITION BY  account_num  ORDER BY CAST(checks_log_date  AS DATETIME) ASC) AS  rnk, order_date, id 
       FROM  check) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rnk+1 = t1.rnk

Comment: it should be dense_rank() not dence_rank()

Comment: try this: 
SELECT t1.account_num
 ,DATEDIFF(day, CAST(t2.checks_log_date AS DATETIME), CAST(t1.checks_log_date AS DATETIME)) as interval
FROM ( 
 SELECT dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY account_num ORDER BY CAST(checks_log_date AS DATETIME ) ASC) AS rnk
  ,checks_log_date, id, account_num FROM [check] ) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY account_num ORDER BY CAST(checks_log_date AS DATETIME) ASC) AS rnk
 ,checks_log_date, id, account_num FROM [check]) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rnk+1 = t1.rnk

Comment: it still returns error :"Error: near "check": syntax error
"

Comment: (1) This answer is way over complicated.  (2) This is not MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
declare @tb table ( id int, order_date datetime)
insert into @tb ( id , order_date )
values ( 1, '2019-08-01' )
, ( 1, '2019-08-04' )
, ( 1, '2019-08-15' )
, ( 2, '2019-08-02' )
, ( 2, '2019-08-16' )


; with cte as ( 
select row_number() over (partition by id order by order_date) as Slno, Id, order_date from @tb)
select t.id, t.order_date , isnull( datediff(day, t1.order_date, t.order_date),0) as Diff 
from cte as t left outer join cte as t1 on t.id=t1.id and t.slno=t1.slno+1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL without the window functions:

```
select t1.id as ID, datediff(dd, convert(datetime, t1.order_date), convert(datetime, t2.order_date)) as DaysBetweenOrders
from orders t1
inner join orders t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where convert(datetime, t2.order_date) =
(select min(convert(datetime, t3.order_date))
from orders t3 where t3.id = t1.id
and convert(datetime, t3.order_date) > convert(datetime, t1.order_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple window function!

```
select t.*,
       datediff(order_date, lag(order_date) over (partition by id)) as diff
from t;
```

In SQL Server, this would be:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, lag(order_date) over (partition by id), order_date) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: I tried your first query, its getting the difference of the 1st date always.

Comment: @metal . . . I thought that was what the OP wanted.  But on looking closer, it is just `lag()`.

Comment: tried to modify your query to work in mysql. select t.*,
       datediff(order_date, lag(order_date) over (partition by id)) as diff
from table1 t;